# php jumping to previous statement inside a loop

Tags: php

So basically i'm trying to create a complex timetable and i have these two methods that each perform a different check function for me:

1. Checks if i have a unique array

   ```
     function tutorAllot($array,$check,$period){
       //check for clashes and return non colliding allotment
       shuffle($array);
       $rKey = array_rand($array);
       if(array_key_exists($array[$rKey]['teacher_id'],  $check[$period]))   {
   return $this->tutorAllot($array,$check,$period);
   }
   return  $tutor = array($array[$rKey]['teacher_id'] =>  $array[$rKey]['subject_code']);
   }
   ```
2. checks that each subject does not appear more than twice in a day

   ```
   function checkDayLimit($data,$check){
       //check double day limit
       $max = 2;
       $value = array_values($check);
       $tempCount = array_count_values($data);
       return (array_key_exists($value[0], $tempCount) && $tempCount[$value[0]] <= $max) ? true : false;

   }
   ```

I'm calling the functions from a loop and populating timetable array only if all conditions area satisfied:

```
    $outerClass = array();
        foreach ($value as $ky => $val) {
            $innerClass = array(); $dayCount = array();
            foreach ($periods[0] as $period => $periodData) {
                $innerClass[$period] = array();
                if(!($periodData == 'break')){
                    $return = $this->Schedule->tutorAllot($val,$clashCheck,$period);
                    if($return){
                        //check that the returned allocation hasnt reached day limit
                        if($this->Schedule->checkDayLimit($dayCount,$return)){
                            $innerClass[$period] += $return;
                            $clashCheck[$period] += $return;
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    $innerClass[$period] = '';
                }
            }
            //debug($innerClass);
            $outerClass[$ky] = $innerClass;
        }
```

**My requirements**

If the checkDayLimit returns false , i want to go back and call tutorAllot function again to pick a new value.
I need to do this without breaking the loop.

I was thinking maybe i could use goto statement but only when am out of options.

Is there a way i can achieve this without using goto statement.
PHP v5.5.3 Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture seems overly complex. Instead of

```
pick at random >> check limit >> if at limit, go to re-pick...
```

Why not incorporate both checks into a single function? It would

1. Filter out data that is not eligible to be picked, and return an array of legitimate choices
2. Pick at random from the safe choices and return the pick

**addendum 1**

I don't think there is any need for recursion. I would use `array_filter` to pass the data through a function that returns `true` for eligible members and `false` for the rest. I would then take the result of `array_map` and make a random selection from it

Comment: since i need the checks separate but with your suggestion i could call the checkDayLimit() from within the tutorAllot () and return safe pick at once or a separate function that calls itself recursively based on the return values of both functions?

Comment: I've added a paragraph

Comment: let me try that out coz recursion has actually thrown a memory limit error

Comment: @GOA You never came back. did my suggestion help resolve your issue?

Comment: Juice Sorry i decided i'll come back to that part  after am done with others in the same app but i'll be sure to check out array_filter and array_map and let you know how it goes